# Placing a self-executing JavaScript function in a 'normal' function

Tags: javascript, function

If I place a self-executing JavaScript function inside a 'normal' function, when is it executed?

```
function normalFunction() {
    var a = 1;

    (function() {
        var b = 2;
        var c = 3;
    })();

    var d = 4;
}
```

Comment: What you expecting to hear? `a` will be seen in self-executing function. `b` and `c` won't be seen outside self-executing function.

Comment: I've rewritten the question to make it clearer that the OP was enquiring about _when_ the function is executed

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The IIFE will *only* be invoked if you call `normalFunction`.  Even though the function block will be parsed at load time, the *invocation* doesn't happen until the enclosing function runs, and then the IIFE gets called with the empty parameter block - `()`

It's almost identical to what would happen if you had written:

```
function normalFunction() {
    var tmp = function() {
        ...
    };

    tmp();
}
```

where clearly `tmp()` only happens during calls to the enclosing function.

Comment: So      var b = 2;
        var c = 3;     will executing even if i don't call normalFunction() ?

Answer (score 2):

Where a self executing function is placed has very little to do with how it executes.  This function will create 2 local variables with initial values, exit and won't have an effect on the enclosing function scope (other than to waste CPU cycles)